# How did Gagarin's flight affect improvements to the Vostok capsule?

Tags: design, vostok-program, crew-module

Every spaceflight is an opportunity to learn what does not work well and to improve the vehicle for the next flight.  **Did Yuri Gagarin's first human spaceflight yield any changes to the capsules or equipment used in later Vostok missions?**

---

*This is part of [6 questions honoring the 60th anniversary of Vostok 1, the first human spaceflight](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746/26446).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> «Восток-2» имел некоторые отличия от первого «Востока». Была доработана радиосвязь, заменена телевизионная система. Телеметрию дополнила коротковолновая система «Сигнал», которая служила для пеленгации корабля и дублировала передачу основных медицинских параметров.

> Vostok-2 had some differences from the first Vostok. The radio communication was improved, the television system was replaced. The telemetry was supplemented by the "Signal" short-wave system, which served for direction finding of the ship and duplicated the transmission of the main medical parameters.

page 18 «Восток2»: Сутки в космосе/"Vostok 2": Day in space

http://epizodyspace.ru/bibl/mpk/mpk.pdf